# How to open OpenCV button menu programmatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, opencv

I used the following code to create an OpenCV window with a back button:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Edit")
cv2.createButton('Back',self.back,None,cv2.QT_PUSH_BUTTON,1)
```

However, when this window is opened, the button does not appear until I click command+P on my Mac. Is there a way I can program the menubar to appear without requiring the user to click command+P every time?

Comment: sounds like a open-cv mac compatibility problem

Comment: can you post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)